# A-Frame object-centric camera rotation

Tags: camera, virtual, aframe, webvr

Ultimately, when using a VR headset, I'd like for the camera to rotate around the object when a viewer's head moves. When I look up, for instance, I want to see the bottom of the object and when I look down, I want to see the top of the object. The google exhibit demos with cardboard have this feature. I'm a newbie when it comes to this stuff, so be gentle. If there are tutorials or literature you'd recommend to become more familiar with this stuff, I'm all ears.

Comment: [orbit-controls](https://github.com/subsumo/aframe-orbit-controls) is the closest thing in A-Frame at this point, but it doesn't support VR headsets yet. That would be a place to start, looking into the the code there and THREE.OrbitControls.